# Проверка на авторизацию пользователя в Class Based View - Django

Tags: django, view

Доброго времени суток, есть Class Based View(generics.CreateView) вот и нужно сделать так что бы не авторизованый пользователь не мог иметь доступа к странице если реализовать вью через метод def someview() то там все просто, а вот как в классе это сделать хоть убей не понятно. Пытался через миксины но тогда выводится пустая страница без формы для авторизованного, прошу помощи, объясните как сделать.
Код вьюхи

```
class LotAddView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Lot

    template_name = 'lots/add_lot.html'
    form_class = LotAddForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        return super(LotAddView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Код формы

```
class LotAddForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(
        label="Наименование",
        widget=forms.TextInput,
        max_length=255
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        label="Описание",
        widget=forms.Textarea,
        max_length=1500
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Lot
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'type_auction', 'time_life', 'price', 'category',)
```

Как описано в urls.py

```
  url(r'^add/$', views.LotAddView.as_view(), name='add'),
```

Если делать через метод то там идет проверка просто через  if request.user.is_authenticated(): а тут просто не понятно куда это засунуть или может есть способ проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к своему классу такой метод:

```
class LotAddView(generic.CreateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(LotAddView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

Либо напишите mixin:

```
class AuthenticatedMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(AuthenticatedMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

и используйте его:

```
class LotAddView(AuthenticatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, еще вопрос так то понятно, а вот про миксин, вы говорите используйте его, просто надо передать и все? Или еще какие то манипуляции в классе?

Comment: Если писать mixin то где? Я попытался выше но ругается на вызов dispatch в коде(return super(AuthenticatedMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)) --Unresolved attribute reference 'dispatch'

Comment: Mixin можно писать где угодно. Лучше всего выделить под них отдельный файл и оттуда импортировать. Но для начала просто разместите его над классом в который будете его добавлять. В классе никаких манипуляций совершать не надо, только добавить как я привёл пример выше. Почему у вас такая ошибка - понять не могу, если можете, пркажите весь код.

Comment: Все работает, это pycharm почему-то подсвечивает и выдает ту ошибку, а если запускать проект то функционал миксина делает свое дело. Сделал так же как и вы описали выделил отдельный файл под миксины, до меня только дошло на сколько это удобная штука вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно использовать готовые mixins для CBV django-braces: https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/